# Checksum of UUIDs in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, uuid, checksum

Is there a way to calculate a checksum of UUIDs in PostgreSQL?

I have a table in PostgreSQL, and in another PostgreSQL database I have a similar table, with (perhaps) the same data. The key is a UUID.

What I want to do is calculate a checksum of all the UUIDs in each table, so I can compare the checksums for both tables. I could read all those keys to my client program and perform the calculations there, but I would prefer to do it on the server. Ideally with a single, simple query. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT md5(string_agg(my_uuid_column::text, '' ORDER BY my_uuid_column)) FROM my_table
```